# Django built in User table alter

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-permissions

I want to alter the built-in User table that comes with django activating admin mode.I heard somewhere that it cannot be altered. And someone suggested to not use the user-table.So if I create a user model on my own , How do I set privileges,permission to the user Like who can add entry to database,who can edit or who can delete.?
And How do set a permission to user that a user can only edit his contents not others?

Comment: Think about using the last version of Django (1.5.0) it seems to provide a new feature to custom the users. More details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/